# Symfony2 - Not able to assign Roles to user (roles array is empty)

Tags: php, arrays, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony2. I am not using FOS UserBundle to implement security.
Followed the Load user documentation in the main website of Symfony.

When I try to see the array of User entity it's showing empty for particular user as shown below

```
    [roles:Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:private] =>
            Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object (
            [_elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] =>
                 Array ( ) )
```

My User Entity class is

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Role;
/**
* Acme\Bundle\UserRegistrationBundle\Entity\User
*
* @ORM\Table(name="acme_users")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
*/

class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $fname;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $lname;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $email;
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
 */
private $gender;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $profession;
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 */
private $date_of_birth;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $country_id;
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $state_id;
        /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $city_id;
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
 */
private $phone_number;
   /**
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean")
 */
private $status;
        /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $is_lock;
        /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $failed_attempt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
 */

private $salt;

 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role",inversedBy="users")
  * @var ArrayCollection $roles;
   */
private $roles;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->status = true;
    $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));

    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();

}
/**
  * Get roles (array)
  *
  * @return array
  */

public function getRoles()
{ 
    return $this->roles->toArray();

}


/**
 * Get user_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set fname
 *
 * @param string $fname
 * @return User
 */
public function setFname($fname)
{
    $this->fname = $fname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fname
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getFname()
{
    return $this->fname;
}

/**
 * Set lname
 *
 * @param string $lname
 * @return User
 */
public function setLname($lname)
{
    $this->lname = $lname;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lname
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getLname()
{
    return $this->lname;
}

/**
 * Set email
 *
 * @param string $email
 * @return User
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get email
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set gender
 *
 * @param string $gender
 * @return User
 */
public function setGender($gender)
{
    $this->gender = $gender;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get gender
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getGender()
{
    return $this->gender;
}

/**
 * Set profession
 *
 * @param string $profession
 * @return User
 */
public function setProfession($profession)
{
    $this->profession = $profession;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get profession
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getProfession()
{
    return $this->profession;
}

/**
 * Set date_of_birth
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateOfBirth
 * @return User
 */
public function setDateOfBirth($dateOfBirth)
{
    $this->date_of_birth = $dateOfBirth;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get date_of_birth
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateOfBirth()
{
    return $this->date_of_birth;
}

/**
 * Set country_id
 *
 * @param integer $countryId
 * @return User
 */
public function setCountryId($countryId)
{
    $this->country_id = $countryId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getCountryId()
{
    return $this->country_id;
}

/**
 * Set state_id
 *
 * @param integer $stateId
 * @return User
 */
public function setStateId($stateId)
{
    $this->state_id = $stateId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get state_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getStateId()
{
    return $this->state_id;
}

/**
 * Set city_id
 *
 * @param integer $cityId
 * @return User
 */
public function setCityId($cityId)
{
    $this->city_id = $cityId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city_id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getCityId()
{
    return $this->city_id;
}

/**
 * Set phone_number
 *
 * @param string $phoneNumber
 * @return User
 */
public function setPhoneNumber($phoneNumber)
{
    $this->phone_number = $phoneNumber;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get phone_number
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPhoneNumber()
{
    return $this->phone_number;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param boolean $status
 * @return User
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set is_lock
 *
 * @param integer $isLock
 * @return User
 */
public function setIsLock($isLock)
{
    $this->is_lock = $isLock;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get is_lock
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIsLock()
{
    return $this->is_lock;
}

/**
 * Set failed_attempt
 *
 * @param integer $failedAttempt
 * @return User
 */
public function setFailedAttempt($failedAttempt)
{
    $this->failed_attempt = $failedAttempt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get failed_attempt
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getFailedAttempt()
{
    return $this->failed_attempt;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 * @return User
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Add roles
 *
 * @param \Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
 * @return User
 */
public function addRole(\Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
{
    $this->roles[] = $roles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove roles
 *
 * @param \Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
 */
public function removeRole(\Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
{
    $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
}

public function eraseCredentials() {

}

public function getUsername() {

}

public function serialize() {


}

public function unserialize($serialized) {


}
}
```

My Role Entity Class is

```
<?php

// src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/Role.php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_roles")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
 class Role implements RoleInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
 * 
 * @var string $role
 */
private $role;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection $users
 */
private $users;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();

}

/**
 * @see RoleInterface
 */
public function getRole()
{
  return $this->role;
 }
/**
 * Set role
 *
 * @param string $role
 * @return Role
 */
public function setRole($role)
{
    $this->role = $role;

    return $this;
}

// ... getters and setters for each property

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Role
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}


/**
 * Add users
 *
 * @param \Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
 * @return Role
 */
public function addUser(\Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
{
    $this->users[] = $users;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove users
 *
 * @param \Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\User $users
 */
public function removeUser(\Autograph\UserBundle\Entity\User $users)
{
    $this->users->removeElement($users);
}

/**
 * Get users
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Show us the controller where you create/set roles to users (Avoid 'very urgent'...).

Comment: i am adding roles directly from phpmyadmin with respect to there id(ok fine will not use it)

Comment: To my mind, your property users in your entity Role is useless. Moreover how are your inserting data in MySQL ? Because array does not exist in MySQL. Maybe it's easier to do it in sf, using form, doctrine and so on.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong. What's the return of `$this->getUser();` in the controller ?

Comment: i am not getting what your asking for ?

Comment: I don't know how you are retrieving the current user. If you try to retrieve it from the controller by printing my code are you sure it's empty ? Because to my mind your code is working.

Comment: Please stop opening new questions for the same problem! If you want to add something to your question, edit the existing question instead of opening a new one. Now you have opened three duplicate questions within a couple of hours: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23380675/1001110, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23382110/1001110 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23382651/1001110.

Comment: i am using $user = new User();
          print_r($user); in the controller to retrive the user details...

Comment: You are creating a new User() by doing this. You are not retrieving the current user. Your array will always be empty. `$this->getUser();` is the good way to do it in Symfony 2.

Comment: can u tell how to print it i am not able to get...

Comment: I can't do it for you. When you are log in, you put `$this->getUser();` in one of your controller's action and you should be able to see all properties of your current user. To me your code is correct. You have nothing to change, just the way you print your current user.

Comment: nothing is printing....